# Reading CSV, getting AD properties of each item and sending an email via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, automation

trying to automate a part of my job that requires me to audit inactive users and email their managers. This report comes in the form of a CSV with several columns. I was hoping to have a PowerShell script that goes through one of the columns, reads the username and gets the ad-properties such as Full name and manager. I would then like to be able to have the script send a pre-canned response to this manager to let them know that their direct report needs to log in.

Example CSV:
Name | username | last log in | etc

I've read in a similar posting that some create an array and store each item in a column into an array such as

$usernames=@()
$usernames+= $_.username

But I am having difficulties fleshing out the rest of the logic once all items are in an array.

Please forgive any issues, this is my first post. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I am having difficulties fleshing out the rest of the logic once all items are in an array.

Once you have an array of usernames, you just need a *loop statement* - like a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($username in $usernames){
    # fetch user account from AD
    $ADUser = Get-ADUser $username -Properties manager,displayName

    # fetch manager account from AD
    $ADManager = Get-ADUser $ADUser.manager -Properties mail,displayName

    # compose email content
    $subject = "'$($ADUser.displayName)' needs to log in!"
    $body = "Dear $($ADManager.displayName),`n`nPlease inform your direct report '$($ADUser.displayName)' that they need to log in!`n`nBest Regards`nMarkM"

    # send email to manager
    Send-MailMessage -From markm@company.tld -Subject $subject -Body $from -SmtpServer mail.server.fqdn
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I appreciate it.